# Draw different polylines in Gmaps for Flutter

Tags: google-maps, flutter, kml, polyline

since there is no plugins for open kml files in flutter, i have extracted all the coords and tried to plot them inside a google map using polylines.

They are 360 pairs of coordinates

[image: Kml de Google Earth]

i am using this code

```
 List<LatLng> tempList = new List<LatLng>();
  for (int i = 0; i <11; i+=2) {
  tempList.clear();
  tempList.add(listaCoords[i]);
  tempList.add(listaCoords[i+1]);
  _circuito1.add(Polyline(
    polylineId: PolylineId(i.toString()),
    points: tempList,
    color: Colors.redAccent.shade700,
    width: 10,
    visible: true,
    geodesic: true,
  ));
}
setState(() {
  lineas.clear();
  lineas.addAll(_circuito1);  
});
//Más código....

return GoogleMap(
  mapType: MapType.hybrid,
  initialCameraPosition: _kGooglePlex,
  onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
  markers: _markers,
  polylines: lineas,
);
```

They don't show up inside the map, but if a decrease the number of points in the Set of polylines, they begin to show up

[image: Otra imagen]

But if a increase these iterations like around 50 different polylines the plot dissapears

I hope you can help me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found the solution! i called native functions of android and imported the KML import utility natively from android to flutter! [image]